# jQuery ajax is making connection, but the response is blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to make a test with ajax response using an external array as a config file...

But it isn't working, i'm getting always a blank response...
Can anyone point me the reason?

Here is the link of jsBin test: http://jsbin.com/udanu/2/edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have bumped into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot make Ajax requests to hosts outside your domain, unless you use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), or some other technique to get around the policy.

You may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for a few popular solutions to work around the SOP (mainly the JSONP, CORS and Reverse Proxy methods):

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: @CuSS: I've updated my answer with a link which you may find interesting.

Comment: i'm trying correcting with: header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST"); AND header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); but they aren't working

Comment: @CuSS: Maybe you'd want to post a new question on this. I don't have much experience with CORS, but I'm sure others on Stack Overflow do.

Answer (score 2):

As you are trying to get data from another domain, maybe you should try using "jsonp" instead of "text" as a dataType.

EDIT: didn't see the previous answer.